# Is it possible to find the memory, string or similar memory copy functions in ppc/mips binary？

Tags: binary, mips, reverse-engineering, powerpc

I just start to analyze the ELF binary file in PPC/MIPS. One day, I have a idea that I want to find all the string or memory copy functions just like strcpy(), strncpy(), memcpy(), memmove() which are implemented by the programmer himself. Is it possible to identify all the similar memory copy functions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not in a 100% reliable way. There seem to be two main issues here.

Firstly, it's not clear what you would classify as a "copy". How do you distinguish a four-byte memory copy with just a load and store of an equally-sized word?

For example, if we compile this:

```c
void assign(long *x, long *y)
{
    *x = *y;
}

void copy(void *x, void *y)
{
    memcpy(x, y, 8);
}
```

We get essentially the same instructions:

```
0000000000000000 <assign>:
   0:   00 00 24 e9     ld      r9,0(r4)
   4:   00 00 23 f9     std     r9,0(r3)
   8:   20 00 80 4e     blr

0000000000000020 <copy>:
  20:   00 00 24 e9     ld      r9,0(r4)
  24:   00 00 23 f9     std     r9,0(r3)
  28:   20 00 80 4e     blr
```

Secondly, even if you have a specific definition for a copy, detecting the presence of that would be extremely difficult to do reliably.

You could implement something that looks for the general pattern of load/store/conditional-branch, but that would only find the trivial cases of a memcpy implementation, and those "implemented by the programmer themseves" could take any form.